# Shopify - change picture while dropdown is open

Tags: shopify, liquid

So, i try to help my friend with an online shop, but is a long time since i did anything in web-dev.
He has a navigation bar at the top with dropdown menues. There should be a picture when no menu is open and this pic should change when one is opened. I think i have to alter the header-desktop-nav.liquid. But i have to admit i do not really know where. Any suggestions?

I do think i have to change/add smth here:

```
  <a href="{{ link.url }}" class="site-nav__link site-nav__link--underline{% if has_dropdown %} site-nav__link--has-dropdown{% endif %}">
    {{ link.title }}
  </a>
  {%- if is_megamenu -%}
    {%- assign previous_column_type = '' -%}
    {%- assign animation_column = 1 -%}

    <div class="site-nav__dropdown megamenu text-left">
      <div class="page-width">
        <div class="grid{% if dropdown_alignment == 'center' %} grid--center{% endif %}">
          <div class="grid__item medium-up--one-fifth appear-animation appear-delay-{{ animation_column }}">
            {%- assign animation_column = animation_column | plus: 1 -%}

            {%- for childlink in link.links -%}
              {%- liquid
                assign create_new_column = false

                if childlink.levels > 0 and forloop.index != 1
                  assign create_new_column = true
                endif

                if childlink.levels == 0 and previous_column_type == 'full'
                  assign create_new_column = true
                endif
              -%}
```

Comment: There isn't an image in your code. You need to add an eventListener to your navigation drop down, then add the code in the eventListener for the image being hidden or visible.